# How to delete graph on click

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Here highchart custom button code I want to close graph on click of custom button.

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            customButton: {
                x: -62,
                onclick: function () {
                    alert("I want to delete graph here");
                },
                symbol: 'circle'
            }
        }
    }
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2F4pJ/383/)**

Comment: Down voter please comment. If you cant give answer leave it but do not down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, there is the method destroy() with a jsfiddle example : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.destroy

[working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02u0h3Lw/)

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
            customButton: {
                x: -62,
                onclick: function () {
                    chart.destroy();
                },
                symbol: 'circle'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `TypeError: chart.destroy is not a function`

Comment: Works fine for me on the fiddle!

Comment: Although it does fire an error after destroying : http://jsfiddle.net/2F4pJ/384/embedded/result/
"a.onContainerClick is not a function" .

See this github issue https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2775

My suggestion : use the exact same solution in the jsfiddle found in the documentation. No use of custom button then, but an external button.

Comment: I had a problem with "a.onContainerClick is not a function" too. I was able to reproduce the bug. It somehow has to do with the event-command-chain. You click on the export-button and first the click event on the button gets triggered. But then there is still the onContainerClick event in the pipeline. If you destroy the chart, the onContainerClick function is called on a null object, cause the chart does no longer exist. I solved this problem, by decoupling the  chart.destroy() action from synchronous program-flow by placing it in setTimeout(function(){...}, 20 ); and the error is gone.